# Can't resolve domain name

Tags: http, bc, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm learning AL programming in BC and I'm experimenting with the HttpClient class to make http requests.
I try to make a request to the jsonplaceholder api but I get a "The remote name could not be resolved: [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts%22). The API is working properly, since I can make a request to it via Postman.
I'm working with BC16, in a docker container supposed to represent a SaaS environment.
Any ideas why I might get this error? The request code is the following:

```
local procedure SendHTTPRequest()
    var
        client: HttpClient;
        responseMessage: HttpResponseMessage;
    begin
        client.Get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        Message(Format(responseMessage.HttpStatusCode));
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that HttpClient requests have been enabled for your extension.

To do that you must do the following:

1. Go to the `Extension Management` page
2. Locate your extension
3. Click the three little dots and choose `Configure`
4. Make sure that `Allow HttpClient Requests` is turned on